# Java Swing Utilities

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a loading message that will popup on the screen while information is being loaded. I will call the initLoadingPanel() method for it so that the JFrame will be visible. My problem is how can I close it?

My code is below.

```
public class DataMigration extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frmDataMigration;

    private JFrame loader;

private JButton btnProcess;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DataMigration window = new DataMigration();
                    window.frmDataMigration.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DataMigration() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        LoggerImp.startLog(CLASS_NAME, "initialize()");

        frmDataMigration = new JFrame();

btnProcess = new JButton("Load");
        btnProcess.setEnabled(false);
        btnProcess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            SwingWorker <CSV, CSV> worker = new SwingWorker<CSV, CSV>() {

                @Override
                protected CSV doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    return FileReaderCSVHelper.fileReader(dirName.getText(), fileName.getText());
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    try {
                        csv = doInBackground();
                        generateTableList(csv.getCsvTitle(), stateController.getFieldNames());
                    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e){

                    }
                    loader.dispose();
                }

            };
            worker.execute();
        }
        });
     frmDataMigration.getContentPane().add(btnProcess);
}

   public void initLoadingPanel(){
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             loader = new JFrame("Loading....");
             ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("loader.gif");
             loader.add(new JLabel(" Loading...", img, JLabel.CENTER));

             loader.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
             loader.pack();
             loader.setSize( 448, 497);
             loader.setVisible(true);
             loader.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you should only need to call `loader.dispose()` or `loader.setVisible(false)`, this then raises the question of, how are you loading your resources?

You will, likely, need to pass a reference of `loader` to the this part of your code, so when it's finished, you can dispose of the frame.

Because the frame is decorated, the user could simply hit the "[x]" button and close the window, while you can set the frames `defaultCloseOperation` to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, it still looks weird.

You could remove the frame decorations using [`JFrame#setUndecorated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean))

Because `loader` extends from `JFrame` it's still possible for the user to interact with the parent window (if one is visible), a better solution might be to use a `JDialog` instead and make it modal.

You might also consider having a look at [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for some other ideas

**Updated**

You're shadowing your variables...

First you declare `loader` as a instance field of `DataMigration`

```
public class DataMigration extends JFrame{
    //...
    private JFrame loader;
```

But then re-declare it within the `run` method of your `Runnable`....

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame loader = new JFrame("Loading....");
```

This means that the instance field is still null, try...

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loader = new JFrame("Loading....");
```

instead...

Also...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    initLoadingPanel();
    csv = FileReaderCSVHelper.fileReader(dirName.getText(), fileName.getText());
    generateTableList(csv.getCsvTitle(), stateController.getFieldNames());
    loader.dispose();
}
```

Isn't going to do what you think it should...you "might" get lucky and the `loader` frame will appear, but it's likely that it won't because you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread.

Instead, you should consider using a `SwingWorker`....

```
initLoadingPanel();
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<CVS, CVS>() {

    @Override
    protected CVS doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return FileReaderCSVHelper.fileReader(dirName.getText(), fileName.getText());
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            cvs = get();
            generateTableList(csv.getCsvTitle(), stateController.getFieldNames());
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        loader.dispose();
    }

};
worker.execute();
```

(I don't know what type `cvs` is, so I'm guessing...

This will ensure that your UI will remain responsive while the data is loaded...

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

**Update with a working example....**

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class DataMigration extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frmDataMigration;

    private JFrame loader;

    private JButton btnProcess;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DataMigration window = new DataMigration();
                    window.frmDataMigration.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DataMigration() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        frmDataMigration = new JFrame();

        btnProcess = new JButton("Load");
        btnProcess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                initLoadingPanel();
                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        return "This is a test value used to highlight the example";
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        try {
                            get();
                        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                        loader.dispose();
                        btnProcess.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                };
                worker.execute();
                btnProcess.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        frmDataMigration.getContentPane().add(btnProcess);
        frmDataMigration.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmDataMigration.pack();
        frmDataMigration.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void initLoadingPanel() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loader = new JFrame("Loading....");
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("loader.gif");
                loader.add(new JLabel(" Loading...", img, JLabel.CENTER));

                loader.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                loader.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                loader.pack();
                loader.setSize(448, 497);
                loader.setVisible(true);
                loader.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm encountering the following error when I call loader.dispose() Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: That's (presumably) because you've declared `loader` within a local context within the `run` method.  Instead of `JFrame loader = new JFrame("Loading....");`, you could try `loader = new JFrame("Loading....");`, assuming that `loader` is declared as an instance variable.  Also note, you should be calling `dispose` within the context of the EDT as well

Comment: Hi I updated my code as per your suggestion but I'm still encountering the error at the line loader.dispose()

Comment: I did a basic, runnable, example (don't have your CVS stuff, so I fudged it)