# Progress indicator in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, progress-bar

I am having a Jasper report where I am exporting it into PDF using the Java code. My java application is in Swing. I need the Java application to display 'Please wait' message while the work is report is properly exported.

I can remember I did this sometime back with just 4 lines of code, I can't remember what they are now. What I managed to do was display a small note in the screen which says "Please Wait" and which disappears as soon as the work is done. As far I can remember, it is a built in Swing functionality.

Comment: I'd recommend that you may need to use a `SwingWorker`, which will allow you to process the exportation of the report outside of the Event Dispatching Thread and can provide you with mechanisms to detect when the the process is completed (so you can close the message).  See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details. Something like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379667/java-swing-utilities/24379773#24379773)

Answer (score -1):

```
> You can use swing worker for that

                        SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() {
                            @Override
                            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                                status.setVisible(true);
                                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                                progressBar.setBackground(getForeground());
                                //do some task & it will return something, like
                                int flag = logRunningThread();
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void done() {
                                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                                progressBar.setBackground(getForeground());
                                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                                //After Success Message 
                                System.out.println("Task Completed")
                                status.setVisible(false);
                                progressBar.setValue(100);
                            }
                        };
                        sw.execute();

Also take 2 variable 
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JLabel status;
& add them to panel & frame.
```

Comment: You should not be interacting with the UI from within the `doInBackground` method, it's kind of the whole point `SwingWorker`